# get value from datacontext of control within an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm sure this is absurdly simple, but it's throwing me for a loop.

I am a collection of controls stored in a list, these controls are dynamically added to my page using an ItemsControl and a wrapPanel.  (This bit works)

I want these controls to dynamically resize based on the width of the page.  To do this I created an IValueConverter which takes a number of columns, and the page width, it then sets the itemwidth in the wrappanel based on this equation (this works)

However, I also need to have some controls be double or triple width.  This is where I'm struggling.  What I have currently is as follows.

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <core:DisplayPageValueConverter x:Key="DisplayPageValueconvert" A="4" />
</ItemsControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <WrapPanel.ItemWidth>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisplayPageValueconvert}">
                    <Binding ElementName="Items"
                                Path="ActualWidth" />
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.WidthFactor" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </WrapPanel.ItemWidth>
        </WrapPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

On the datacontext.widthfactor, rather than getting the datacontext of the control being added to the ItemsControl, it's instead getting the datacontext of the page itself.

If anyone knows of a way to make this work, or an alternate workaround it would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried the following instead

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Width>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisplayPageValueconvert}">
                    <Binding ElementName="Items"
                                         Path="ActualWidth" />
                    <Binding Path="DataContext.WidthFactor" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Width>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

However this gets skipped as the items in the ItemSource are already controls, and I get the following error in my output window.

ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='MyControl'

Comment: Maybe a Grid works for you. You can define rows and/or columns and set the width/height. You can define e.g. 2/3 width for the first row and 1/2 width for the second row as well.

Comment: How are you supposed to be able to bind the Width of a single WrapPanel to the WidthFactor property of *each* item that gets added to the ItemsControl? There is a single WrapPanel and several items in the ItemsControl, right?

Comment: @mm8 you have made a very good point, and I am now slapping myself.  i suppose I'd need to set the width for each control individually based on the wrap panel width instead.

And Mighty, I did consider a grid, but we'll have different controls of different width factors on different rows.  Using numbers to represent the width factor on a control row 1 may have a single control that takes up full width, row 2 may have two double wide controls, or four single wide, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank you to mm8 for pointing out that I'm an idiot (my words not his) as I was trying to set the ItemWidth of the wrappanel, which would set the width for each item to the same value.

In the end I went with my second approach, and modified it so it actually worked.  Instead of storing a collection of MyControl in my viewmodel, instead I store a collection of MyControlViewModel.

Now in my xaml file I have the following

```
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <core:DisplayPageValueConverter x:Key="DisplayPageValueconvert"
                                            A="4" />
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <views:MyControl DataContext="{Binding}">
                <views:MyControl.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DisplayPageValueconvert}">
                            <Binding ElementName="Items"
                                     Path="ActualWidth" />
                            <Binding Path="WidthFactor" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </views:MyControl.Width>
            </views:MyControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Which handles the layout I wanted pretty much exactly.  Can't believe I missed it before.  [facepalm]